# Не исчезает кнопка.

Tags: php

Хо!=) 
Есть вот такой код.

```
 $wt=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`);
while($w=@mysql_fetch_array($wt)){
$wb = $w['zz'];
}
if ( $wb != '1'){ echo '<script> function refr() {setTimeout("document.location.reload()", 1000);} </script> <form onsubmit="refr();" action="" method="POST" target="_self"><input class="button-small" type="submit" name="sm"  value="Press" /></form>';}

if (isset($_POST['sm'])) {  
    try {
    {
Выполняем запрос в бд на добавление в поле zz значение 1
 }}catch (Exception $e) { die("<p>Server error! Please contact the admin.</p>");
}}
```

После чего страница обновляется, значение в бд добавляется, но кнопка исчезает только при повторном обновлении страницы.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так перенесите код if (isset($_POST['sm'])) выше кода выборки 'zz' из таблицы